# A linear functional on $C(K)^*$ continuous on each $L_1(\mu)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $K$ be a (Hausdorff) compact topological space, ${\mathcal C}(K)$ the usual Banach space of continuous functions $x:K\to{\mathbb C}$, ${\mathcal C}(K)^*$ the Banach dual space of measures.

For each measure $\mu\in{\mathcal C}(K)^*$, $\mu\ge 0$, consider the natural mapping 
$$
\varPhi_\mu: L_1(\mu)\to {\mathcal C}(K)^*\quad\Big|\quad \varPhi_\mu(f)=f\cdot\mu,\quad f\in L_1(\mu),
$$
or, more precisely,
$$
\varPhi_\mu(f)(x)=\int_K x(t)\cdot f(t)\cdot\mu(d t),\quad f\in L_1(\mu),\quad x\in {\mathcal C}(K).
$$
Let $p:{\mathcal C}(K)^*\to{\mathbb C}$ be a linear functional, which is continuous on each subspace $L_1(\mu)$, i.e. for any $\mu$ the composition $p\circ\varPhi_\mu$ is continuous (=bounded) on the Banach space $L_1(\mu)$ (with the usual norm).

> Is $p$ continuous on ${\mathcal C}(K)^*$? (In other words, is $p$ an element of ${\mathcal C}(K)^{**}$?)

P.S. I asked this also at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234648/a-linear-functional-on-ck-continuous-on-each-l-1-mu/234652#234652).

Comment: I'm lost with your definition of $\Phi_\mu(f)$. if $K = [a,b]$, is it $\Phi_\mu(f)(g) =  \int_a^b f g d\mu$  for any function $g$ continuous on $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: what about $p \circ \Phi_\mu$ ? what is it ?

Comment: It's the usual concatenation of mappings.

Comment: Note that $\Phi_\mu f$ is always a finite measure (I guess, by $f\mu$ you mean $f\,d\mu$?)

Comment: If you assume that the norm of $\rho\circ\Phi_\mu$ is bounded then the answer is clearly yes, since $\mu=\Phi_u1$ so $|\rho\mu|\le c||1||_{L^1(\mu)}=c||\mu||$.

Comment: Yes, $f\mu$ is $f d\mu$. (I would write, $\varPhi_\mu(f)(x)=\int_K x(t)f(t)\mu(d t)$).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Why is $1\in L^1(\mu)$?

Comment: Because $\mu(K)<\infty$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Because $K$ is compact. I missed this.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp More precisely, because $|\mu|(K)<\infty$. That's true just because $\mu$ is a complex measure; if $\mu$ is any complex measure then $|\mu|$ is a _finite_ (positive) measure.

Comment: David, the constant $c$ is different for each measure $\mu$! So your remark does not work.

Comment: That's different then - I said _if_ you assume the norm of $\rho\circ\Phi_\mu$ is bounded.  Offhand I don't know the answer - my tendency would be to try to show that in fact the norm _is_ bounded, by some Banach-space magic. Reminds one of the Uniform Boundedness Principle, not that I see exactly how that would apply.

Comment: Possibly there was some confusion: Saying the norm of $\rho\circ\Phi_\mu$ is bounded is saying that $||\rho\circ\Phi_\mu||\le c$ for all $\mu$. Not at all the same as saying that $\rho\circ\Phi_\mu$ is bounded, which says just that the norm is _finite_.

Comment: David, I don't assume that $\sup_{||\mu||\le 1}||p\circ\varPhi_\mu||<\infty$. I assume only that $\forall \mu$ $||p\circ\varPhi_\mu||=C_\mu<\infty$. So actually, the question is if $C_\mu$ are bounded for $||\mu||\le 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Proof much simplified.

Yes, it's true.

I'm going to write $N(\mu)$ for what we've been calling $C_\mu$. So $N(\mu)$ is the smallest constant such that $$|p(f\mu)|\le N(\mu)\int|f|\,d|\mu|$$for $f\in L^1(\mu)$.

**Lemma 0** If $c$ is a non-zero constant then $N(c\mu)=N(\mu)$.

More generally:

**Lemma 1** If $f\in L^1(\mu_1)$ and $\mu_2=f\mu_1$ then $N(\mu_2)\le N(\mu_1)$.

Proof: If $g\in L^1(\mu_2)$ then $$|p(g\mu_2)|=|p((gf)\mu_1|
\le N(\mu_1)\int|gf|\,d|\mu_1|=N(\mu_1)\int|g|\,d|\mu_2|.$$

**Theorem** $\sup_\mu N(\mu)<\infty$.

Proof. Suppose on the other hand that there exists a sequence $\mu_n$ of measures with $N(\mu_n)\to\infty$. By Lemma 0, wlog $\sum||\mu_n||<\infty$. Let $\mu=\sum|\mu_n|$. Then $\mu_n<<\mu$, so Lemma 1 shows that $N(\mu)\ge N(\mu_n)$.

Comment: David, I have to go to the university now, I'll check this later. Excuse me, I thought, after first comments people lost interest to this question, that's why I asked this also at MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234648/a-linear-functional-on-ck-continuous-on-each-l-1-mu/234652#234652 When I'll come back, I'll look at your answer, thank you anyway!

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Well that sucks. If you'd told me that you were only going to wait three blessed hours before saying "nobody answered" I wouldn't have spent the time I did on the question! Next time you have a question please specify the time limit. I mean really, after _three hours_ you conclude that people had lost interest? The idea that someone might be thinking about it never occurred to you? Or that someone might have something other than MSE to do? What's irritating about this is that my current version appeared an hour after Nate posted the same solution. I don't like how that looks.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I guess I should be satisfied that at least my _first_ much more complicated version appeared an hour before Nate's answer. But the current version is the same as what he said, looks just like I saw his post and copied it. _Three_ hours is much too long to wait - I see your point, my apologies for being so slow.

Comment: David, excuse me, that was my fault. I can promise you that I will mention you (together with Nate Eldredge) in my paper as the author of this result. I am really sorry.

Comment: I only don't understand your notations. What is $N(\mu)$?

Comment: @NateEldredge This looks like plagiarism. It's not. I had no idea the OP was going to repost on MO after waiting only three hours for an answer here or I would have checked there before posting this.

Comment: David, in any case Nate is not guilty, that was only my fault. I think, we can speak about this in Meta. Perhaps, moderators could resolve this somehow.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The definition of $N(\mu)$ would have appeared before you asked the question except that my web browser crashed. Once again my apologies. Of course Nate had nothing to do with it - why would you think I thought otherwise? This is going to be part of a _paper_? Has any part of that paper taken you more than three hours to write? You'd better hope the editors don't find out.

Comment: David, pardon, I did not understand about plagianism. Yes, I need this lemma for my work. I used to think that if a question disappers from the main page of the website, it usually means that it is not interesting for people. I asked this here because I stuck in this. I will send you the paper when (and if) it will be finished. It is about envelopes in Functional Analysis, you can make an impression here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2424 (this is the last my paper on this topic, and what I asked here will be a part of the next paper).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I just saw this (never got pinged).  Certainly I didn't suspect you of plagiarism!  I'll likewise plead not guilty: your original answer was posted here before mine on MO, but I didn't see it.  Clearly we just independently came up with similar solutions.  I was also frustrated by the rapid crossposting that resulted in us duplicating our efforts, but I recognize that the conventions of SE can be unclear, and I think Sergei now understands what to do in the future.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually I didn't suspect you of suspecting me of plagiarism, my comment was more sort of just for the record. It does _look_ a lot like plagiarism: The version I posted before yours was much more complicated, then I saw the much simpler second version and posted it an hour after you'd posted more or less the same thing.